Indian TV show about some lost kids finding their way back to home
I've seen this kids TV show on Indian Television between 2003-2007. It was about some kids who lost their way to home and try to find it. It was not animated though.
It was in Hindi language and possibly aired on Star Plus or Doordarshan National.
Plot Details:
There are some kids playing football. One of them kicks the ball that goes into a truck. They follow it but lost the track and try to get back to their home. During their way back to home, they used to get into some trouble from like crooks etc. It was a metropolitan city where they were lost. Their parents also search for them meanwhile.
As far as I remember, in the end, one guy who was a relative of a kid finds him, and with the help of that kid, all of them were found.
That complete show is about how they do get back to their homes. It went for two-three months, about 50 episodes.

Was it Cambala Investigation Agency? I don't remember the exact plot but there was one episode where the kids lose their way back home and their parents are searching for them.

No, it was complete series revolving sround the plot I mentioned.

Are the lead roles children?

@SS. Can't say, but the plot revolves around them, most of it.
